# Yii get variable from other function in same Controller

Tags: php, yii

Is that possible to get variable from other function in same Controller ?

**So I just updated my code  ... the huge code is my real code ... so I wish to get the `$hashfilename_filename` to another function so I able to save it into DB**

Example:

```
 class HappyController extends Controller{

   public function actionUploadFile()
{               

    if (isset($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])) {                      

        $today = date("Ymd");     

        $slash = Yii::app()->params['slash'];   
        $tmp_folder = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'];
        $tmp_folder_with_index_file = $tmp_folder . $slash . 'index.html';
        $tmp_folder_with_date = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] . $today;      

        if (!is_dir($tmp_folder_with_date)){

            mkdir($tmp_folder_with_date, 0755);                     
            copy($tmp_folder_with_index_file, $tmp_folder_with_date . $slash . 'index.html');
        }                   

        $filesize = sprintf("%u", filesize( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] )); 

        $hashfilename_filename = md5(time() + 1) . '.apk';  

        $full_path = $tmp_folder_with_date . $slash . $hashfilename_filename;

        if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){             
            $result['statusCode'] = "500";  
            echo json_encode($result);      
            die();
        }                       

        $result['statusCode'] = "200";          
        $result['today'] = $today;  
        $result['tmp_folder_with_date'] = $tmp_folder_with_date;        
        $result['filesize'] = $filesize;    
        $result['hashfilename_filename'] = $hashfilename_filename;  
        $result['full_path'] = $full_path;  


    }else{
        $result['statusCode'] = "400";          
    }       

    echo json_encode($result);      
    die();
}


public function actionLife(){
     $model = new ThisisLife();
     $model->sad   = $hashfilename_filename;
     $model->save();
    }


}
```

**In public function actionLife , I wish to get the variable from other function, any suggestion to do that ?**

Comment: Declare the valuable as public globally.

Answer (score 2):

try storing it in a session variable;

```
 public function actionAbc(){
    $full_path = a + b;
    Yii::app()->user->setState('full_path', $full_path);
 }

 public function actionXyz(){
    $full_path =  Yii::app()->user->getState('full_path');
 }
```

In this way you can access this variable from anywhere across whole platform.

Comment: It is a variable, So use "echo" instead of "print_r".

Comment: i think the problem not about print_r or echo ... is when move to function the variable data not longer exist

Comment: No. i dont think that is the case because i have been using this in my project and its working fine.Once you set a particular variable using setState,you can get that variable's value using getState from anywhere(model,view,controller) across platform.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not the right way in my opinion. The idea behind OOP i to encapsulate code belonging together. So if you need to determine a path which is needed in more than one place (or action) just extract it into its own private function within the controller. That way you could call this method from both actions and reuse your code.

If you need this variable between two calls I'd rather pass it as a GET/POST-Parameter as the otherway around you risk using the same filename again if you forget to reset the var...as it says, it lasts the whole session!

Your method could look like this:

```
private function generatePath()
{ 
    $folder = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] . date("Ymd");
    $folderWithIndex = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.html';

    if (!file_exists($folder)) {
        mkdir($folder, 0755);
        copy($folderWidthIndex, $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.html');
    }

    $filename = md5(time() + 1) . '.apk';    
    return $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
}
```

The constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a php default constant to automatically fill in the "slash" of the current filesystem.
One more input: Instead of defining the path in your params, you could set it as a yii-alias. This makes life much easier in the long run. Make sure to check it out here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-aliases.md

I hope it helped!

cheers, pascal

Comment: I know. Read both my answer and the one from Sagar. All those soutions will work. Following input: if you need to get it from one function to another within THE SAME REQUEST focus on my answer. If you need to pass it between TWO REQUESTS, focus on the answer of Sagar, especially the state-part (the part with storing it in a session variable wouldn't be a good solution as it is error-prone...but i think he removed it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access variable through controllers, why don't u make it a private field in controller. So that you can access it in whole Controller class. You then may have getter, setters if needed, as it should as we are talking about OOP.